# Autofilter up to last row of sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 30,000+ rows to filter. I need to filter the values that starts with 314 in column F. I have the following code to filter up to a specific range. Turns out the sheet will be changed in a monthly basis. So there should be no definite last row to indicate in the code and I need to find the last row of the sheet(last row changes every month). I tried tweaking the code, but it doesn't work. This is the code I tweaked:

```
Sub Del314()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Source")
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("A1:AF" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*", Operator:=xlAnd

ws.Range("A2:AF" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

While this is the original code (Where it targets just a specific range, up to row 30436):

```
Sub Del314()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")

ws.Range("$A$1:$AF$30436").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*" _
, Operator:=xlAnd

Dim LR As Long
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A2:AF" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub'
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _I tried tweaking the code, but it doesn't work._  So... what happens?

Comment: It doesn't sort the values that begins with 314 in column F and and it also doesn't also delete those values. The sheet just stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Del314()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Source")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("a1:af1").Resize(lr).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*", Operator:=xlAnd

    ws.Range("a2:af2").Resize(lr - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Try an object variable instead...

```
Public Sub Del314()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Source")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
    Set r = ws.Range("a1:af1").Resize(lr)

    r.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*", Operator:=xlAnd

    r.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

EDIT #2:

Though I hate doing this, let's try selecting the range first...

```
Public Sub Del314()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Source")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = ws.Range("a1:af1").Resize(lr)
    r.Select

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*", Operator:=xlAnd

    r.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

EDIT #3:

OK. One more variation...

```
Public Sub Del314()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Source")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = ws.Range("a1:af1").Resize(lr)

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    r.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=314*", Operator:=xlAnd

    r.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: The sheet stays the same. Doesn't sort and delete rows.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Excel and/or the computer? Something strange going on there. But, you can also try an object variable. Se edit in my answer.

Comment: I tried both codes. Still doesn't work. I've also restarted my computer. The sheet still stays the same.

Comment: Can you do a break point on the newest code I posted, just after "r" is set? In the Immediate Window, what is the value of: r.Address    ?

Comment: The value is Nothing. It detects the last row (31284) and selects it. But it doesn't sort and delete the entire row if the values in column F starts with 314

Comment: It selects the last row? Or does it select all the rows down to and including row 31284? The value of r.Address should not be Nothing! It should be: $A$1:$AF$31284. I am trying to confirm that before looking at other things.

Comment: It selects all the rows down to row 31283, not 31284. $A$1:$AF$31284 doesn't show up when I tried to break

Comment: Sorry to keep coming back to this, but we must know the value of r.Address. Make sure you have a break point set just after r is set to the range. Run the procedure. When it stops on the break point, click on the Immediate Window (or simply type CTRL-G). From there enter this (and then press Enter on the keyboard): PRINT r.address

Comment: OK. Thanks. Now we know for sure that the proper range is being acted upon. See Edit #2.

Comment: I tried Edit #2. A Runtime Error '1004' Select method of Range class failed appeared.

Comment: After reviewing all of this, I suspect the problem is that the worksheet already had a filter on. In my Edit #3 I specifically turn of filtering just prior to adding the filter you want. Please advise whether this worked.

Comment: Hello. Yes, you're right. I overlooked the sheet, it has a filter on. I tried the latest edit, and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help!